# Routing issue with Slim framework

Tags: php, url-routing, slim

I just got started with Slim. My application for the moment is something like this:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim([
    'debug' => true
]);

var_dump($app->request());

$app->get('/:name', function ($name) {
    echo "Hello, $name";
});

$app->get('/', function () {
    echo 'hello world';
});

$app->run();
```

I am running it on localhost using PHP built in web server. For every request I try in the browser (or Postman, or CURL), what I get is always "hello world", as if the first route is not considered. Moreover, if I remove the second route, I always get a 404.

Am I forgetting something?

For debugging purposes, which HTTP header is used by SLIM to determine the route?

Comment: Yes, can you please share your web project structure and the .htaccess file(s) ? Is the current project a Slim skeleton ?

Comment: I'm not using a Slim skeleton. My index.php is inside a public folder. I'm using PHP built in web server, so I have no .htaccess file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, I found out that the problem was given by a wrong document root.

I was launching the application from the main folder of my project using `php -S localhost:8080 public/index.php` and this caused the `PATH_INFO` header of the HTTP request not to be compiled.

Changing directory to `./public` and launching the app using `php -S localhost:8080 index.php` solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove the second route `$app->get('/')` as it is the Home default route and it is quite normal to get a 404 because `$app->get('/:name', function ($name) {})` is expecting a callback function's argument `'name'` that is missing.

Are you trying the following:

```
http://localhost/mysite/  --- Outputs Hello World
http://localhost/mysite/marcosh  --- Outputs a 404 ??
```

If this is the case then as a77icus5 suggested we may need to look into your htacess file and what is the project directory structure...

I have a fresh [Slim Skeleton](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton) install and I thought I'd share my configuration with you...

My Web project directory is as follow :

```
Webroot
-htaccess
- public
-- htaccess
-- assets
--- js
--- css
- templates
- app
- vendor
-- Slim
-- Twig
```

In the first `.htaccess` located in the project root directory I added :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here `public` matches the name of the app public folder

Then in the `.htaccess` located in the public folder I added :

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Then in SLIM -> Environment.php (line 142 - Virtual Path ) and try to edit as follow :

```
  // Virtual path
    // $env['PATH_INFO'] = substr_replace($requestUri, '', 0, strlen($physicalPath)); // <-- Remove physical path
        $env['PATH_INFO'] = str_replace(str_replace('/public', "", dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])), '', "/".$requestUri); // remove public from URI
        $env['PATH_INFO'] = str_replace('?' . $queryString, '', $env['PATH_INFO']); // <-- Remove query string
        $env['PATH_INFO'] = '/' . ltrim($env['PATH_INFO'], '/'); // <-- Ensure leading slash
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of url rewriting for Slim to work. Since you are using internal PHP webserver you cannot use `mod_rewrite`. Instead create `route.php` file to same folder as `index.php` with following code.

```
<?php

# Used only for running the app with internal PHP webserver
# php -S localhost:8080 route.php

if (file_exists(__DIR__ . "/" . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
    return false;
} else {
    include_once "index.php";
}
```

Then run it with `php -S localhost:8080 route.php`. Everything works now as expected.

```
$ curl --include http://localhost:8080/foo
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.2
Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8

Hello, foo
```

Comment: I tried your approach, but with no results. with /foo, I get hello world and with / I get a 404

Comment: Code works for me. You might be running many webservers and accessing the wrong one.