# Route parameters with Slim 3 & built-in PHP server

Tags: php, slim

I'm having problems getting routes with parameters to work in Slim 3 RC.

```
$app->get('/hello/:name', function($req, $res, $args) {
    echo "Hello {$name}";
});
```

Visiting `/hello/joe` results in 404.

Other routes work fine, e.g.:

```
$app->get('/', HomeAction::class . ":dispatch");

$app->get('/services', ServicesAction::class . ":dispatch");
```

I am using the built-in PHP server while I am developing. I do not have any `.htaccess` file. I have tried the suggested `route.php` suggestion and the accepted answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29594685/routing-issue-with-slim-framework) but it does not work. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Slim 3 you need to change `:name` in `{name}`.

```
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response->write("Hello " . $args['name']);
});
```

You can find the documentation [here](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/).

Comment: Thank you. Amazing how many times I looked at the version3-specific documentation while debugging this one but somehow missed the syntax change :-)